On the convergence of the value of a state of the square of an approximate identity
Let $\omega$ be a positive linear functional over a $C^*$-algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ and $E_\alpha$ be an approximate identity of $\mathfrak{A}$.
Then, I understand that
\begin{equation}
\|\omega\| = \lim_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha)
\end{equation}
because it is evident that $\omega(E_\alpha) \geq \omega(E_\beta)$ if $\alpha \geq \beta$.
But Proposition 2.3.11 of Bratteli-Robinson states that in addition we have
\begin{equation}
\|\omega\| = \lim_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha^2).
\end{equation}
Reading the proof, I understand
\begin{equation}
\|\omega\| = \sup_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha^2)
\end{equation}
but it is not proven that $\omega(E_\alpha^2)$ converges to $\sup_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha^2)$, which is not evident to me because I do not know if $\omega(E_\alpha^2)$ is increasing or not.

Generally, the definition of an approximate identity in a $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ is a net $\{E_\alpha\}_\alpha$ of positive contractions s.t. $\lim_\alpha xE_\alpha = \lim_\alpha E_\alpha x = x$ for all $x \in A$. Under this definition, one has the classical result that $\|\omega\| = \lim_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha)$ for any positive linear functional $\omega$.
Under this definition, it is the case that if $\{E_\alpha\}_\alpha$ is an approximate identity, then so is $\{E_\alpha^2\}_\alpha$. Clearly, $E_\alpha^2$ are positive contractions. Let $x \in A$, $\epsilon > 0$. Then for large $\alpha$, we have $\|xE_\alpha - x\| < \epsilon/2$. Thus, for large $\alpha$, as $\|E_\alpha\| \leq 1$,
$$\|xE_\alpha^2 - x\| \leq \|xE_\alpha^2 - xE_\alpha\| + \|xE_\alpha - x\| < \|xE_\alpha - x\|\|E_\alpha\| + \epsilon/2 < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$$
Hence, $xE_\alpha^2 \to x$. One may similarly prove that $E_\alpha^2 x \to x$. This shows $\{E_\alpha^2\}_\alpha$ is an approximate identity, so the result follows.

In case the OP is more familiar with approximate identities requiring $E_\alpha \leq E_\beta$ when $\alpha \leq \beta$, here is a more direct proof that $\|\omega\| = \lim_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha^2)$, as well as a proof that $\|\omega\| = \lim_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha)$ for all approximate identities $\{E_\alpha\}_\alpha$ in the definition I wrote down, without assuming it is increasing.
Assume WLOG that $\|\omega\| = 1$. For any $x \in A$, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$|\omega(x)|^2 = \lim_\alpha |\omega(xE_\alpha)|^2 \leq \liminf_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha x^\ast xE_\alpha) \leq \|x\|^2\liminf_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha^2)$$
So $1 = \|\omega\|^2 \leq \liminf_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha^2)$. It is clear that $\limsup_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha^2) \leq 1$, so $\lim_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha^2) = 1 = \|\omega\|$.
Altering the proof slightly, we see that $\lim_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha) = 1$ as well. Indeed, as $E_\alpha^2 \leq E_\alpha$, we have,
$$1 \leq \liminf_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha^2) \leq \liminf_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha) \leq \limsup_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha) \leq 1$$
So $\lim_\alpha \omega(E_\alpha) = 1 = \|\omega\|$, where we observe the proof does not need $E_\alpha$ being increasing.

Thank you very much for teaching the alternative proof without assuming $E_\alpha$ being increasing!
